# Bamboo does not automatically create branch in the plan

Tags: bamboo

**Bamboo:**

On my current build plan I've checked an option create branch plan when new branch in repository is created and matches expression and set value **hotfix***

Repository from the Bitbucket is of course linked to this build plan.

**Bitbucket:**

I have created branch named **hotfix/test** in Bitbucket git repository and set Bamboo plan branch.

After several hours branch was not automatically created and I have no idea what do I wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this by making the following changes:

1. Changed match pattern from **hotfix*** to **hotfix/.***
2. Be also sure, that new hotfix repository you're creating in Bitbucket doesn't have activity older than you've set in other option Delete plan branch - After branch inactivity in repository.